# Pandas datetime format to include 'T'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple datetime columns with this format:

```
2019-02-19 09:47:45.285
```

the required format is:

```
2019-02-19T09:47:45.285
```

Tried with the following code, but I get the same thing:

```py
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: Your code is parsing the datetime, not formatting the output.

Comment: what *requires* that format. Is it some other python library? (Does it really need strings, or does it require datetime) or is it some thing where you just export away from pandas. If the latter you _should_ probably leave the datetime as it is with pandas and instead use the `date_format` argument of to_csv at the very end. Once your .strfime you lose all datetime functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format` parameter tells `pd.to_datetime` how to parse the date. Since it supports the format of your dates automatically, I'd remove that.

What you really want is to format your date back to a string, and you can use `column.dt.strftime` with your format for that:

```
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(pd.to_datetime).apply(lambda col: col.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```